# cs cart (php, apache) links on local computer doesn't work. reciving 404error

Tags: php, apache, mamp, cs-cart, localserver

I've copied my cs cart to my local computer and set up, and configure how it should be.

Cs cart opens, and run - everything looks fine.
Admin panel is working, and all flow between pages on panel admin is fine.

But I can't move between pages on store front.
And I'm reciving 404

After cliks on link url looks like: 
http://localhost:8888/sitename.pl/index.php?dispatch=%2F**sitename.pl**%2F**category**%2F

Instead of online version, like:
https://sitename.pl/category/

But when I'm trying manualy type: "localhost:8888/sitename.pl/category/"
I'm reciving 404 as well.

This is part of my config file looks like this:

```
// Host and directory where software is installed on no-secure server
$config['http_host'] = 'localhost:8888';
$config['http_path'] = '/sitename.pl';

// Host and directory where software is installed on secure server
$config['http_host'] = 'localhost:8888';
$config['http_path'] = '/sitename.pl';
```

And my cs cart is in folder "sitename.pl" inside my htdocs

Im using MAMP on Os X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allright I find how to fix this.

It seems that the mod_rewrite module is not installed or installed incorrectly on your local machine.

We need to disable the SEO add-on on the Add-ons > Manage add-ons page in the admin panel of your store and check whether the issue is still here.

Comment: plus in security setting disable secure connection for the storefront

Comment: For the past 3-4 hours I was trying to find the solution. They don't even have it in their documentation? They have a doc explaining how to reverse proxy using varnish cache and they have mentioned there to run the app on 8080 but failed to explain that SEO addon will mess it up....
 
Thanks a lot mate! This helped me!